# Can't get attribute from metaclass

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error when I run this app:

> AttributeError: type object 'ScientistObject' has no attribute 'fields'

Here's ScientistObject

```
class ScientistObject(StandardValueObject):
  first_name  = fields.Primitive()
  last_name   = fields.Primitive()
```

Here's the **init** for StandardValueObject

```
class StandardValueObject(object):
    __metaclass__ = ValueObjectMeta

    def __init__(self, filtered_data):
        super(StandardValueObject, self).__init__()

        self._fields = type(self).fields
        self._values = {
            name: field.init(filtered_data.get(field.key, None))
                for name, field in self._fields.iteritems()
        }
```

That self._fields = type(self).fields is the line that throws the error, incidentally.

I've also got a fields.py where class Field(object) is defined.

ValueObjectMeta is:

```
class ValueObjectMeta(type):

fields = None

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):

        attrs[b'fields'] = {}

        for attr in [attr for attr, field in attrs.iteritems() if isinstance(field, Field)]:
            field = attrs.pop(attr)

            if not field.key:
                field.key = attr

            attrs[b'fields'][attr] = field

        return super(ValueObjectMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
```

Shouldn't ScientistObject be able to get fields from the metaclass?

Comment: Why have you decorated ValueObjectMeta's __new__ method with @staticmethod?

Comment: What version of python are you using? `fields` in `ScientistObject` are from your class? or they defined somewhere else?